# How do i make my test wait that my verticle is fully deployed to start?

Tags: java, unit-testing, openapi, vert.x

i'm having a bit of trouble trying to write some tests for my vertx api. I'm using open-api to set the route using a scheme that i download from an api-curio schema registry. My app is working but when i tried to make tests, some of them weren't working properly. It seems like my test is executing himself before the route is actually set. How can i get my test to wait before executing himself ?

Here is the problematic part of my tests :

```
@BeforeEach
void deploy_verticle(Vertx vertx, VertxTestContext testContext) {
  mainVerticle = new MainVerticle();
  client = vertx.createHttpClient();
  ConfigStoreOptions propertyFile = new ConfigStoreOptions()
    .setType("file")
    .setFormat("properties")
    .setConfig(new JsonObject().put("path", "src/main/resources/local_config.properties"));
  ConfigRetrieverOptions options = new ConfigRetrieverOptions()
    .addStore(propertyFile);
  ConfigRetriever retriever = ConfigRetriever.create(vertx, options);
  retriever.getConfig(config -> vertx.deployVerticle(mainVerticle, new DeploymentOptions().setConfig(config.result()), testContext.succeedingThenComplete()));
}
```

This test isn't working properly even if my api is working perfectly :

```
@Test
void listEmployeTest(Vertx vertx, VertxTestContext testContext) throws Throwable {
  HttpClient client = vertx.createHttpClient();
  client.request(HttpMethod.GET, 8080, "localhost", "/v2.3/employes/").compose(request -> request.send()).onSuccess(body -> {
    assertEquals(200, body.statusCode());
    testContext.completeNow();
  }).onFailure(failure -> testContext.failNow(failure));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so i managed to find the solution to my problem !
First i tried to use

```
testContext.awaitCompletion(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```

to make the test wait for the full deployement of my routes.

After that i looked at my main Verticle code and refactored it to complete the start Promise only when every route is deployed so that when the tests starts i already know that the route are already built. So i no longuer needed to wait in my tests before trying to ping my routes.

Answer (score 0):

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html

It is meant for threaded environments, though.

Comment: I've not tried it but the vertx threads aren't supposed to be stopped like that i think. I'll give it a try though.
Thanks for your answer !